# Linked posts lead to a 404 in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

[Here](https://mooncrater31.github.io/infer/) is a sample site that I'm developing. The clickable map for 6 states should lead to another post. The top-most state( Jammu and Kashmir) should lead to a post `2018-09-20-jkGIF` that is in the `_posts`folder. Similar actions should be performed for the other states as well.

The problem here is that, the click leads to a 404 page. The local serving of the site does this task easily, but the github backed version doesn't.

Files in my `_posts` folder:

```
2018-09-19-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
2018-09-20-jkGIF.md
2018-09-21-aniGIF.md
2018-09-21-chanGIF.md
2018-09-21-dadraGIF.md
2018-09-21-damanGIF.md
2018-09-21-goaGIF.md
```

The `_config.yml` looks like :

```
title: Your awesome title
email: your-email@example.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
baseurl: "infer" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll


markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
```

And the post linking procedure in the `home` page in the `_layouts` folder is:

```
href={% post_url 2018-09-20-jkGIF %}
```

(Inside that of a map, for more information dive into [this](https://github.com/mooncrater31/infer/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/home.html).)

The posts contain a GIF. These GIFs are in the root folder, and are linked to the pages in the following way:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Jammu And Kashmir GIFs"
---
![useful image]({{ site.url }}jk.gif)
```

I tried adding a slash before the `jk.gif` thing, but that didn't work. The posts don't seem to be linked to the home page.

---

You can check out [this](https://github.com/mooncrater31/infer) repository if needed, or just ask away in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your base url : `baseurl: "/infer"`, and use it :

```
href={{ site.baseurl }}{% post_url 2018-09-20-jkGIF %}
```

and

```
![useful image]({{ site.baseurl }}/jk.gif)
```